# \<setminus> Isabelle syntax

Tags: syntax, set, isabelle

I just cant find the syntax for removing a term from a set.

I have the following:

```
typedecl STUDENT

definition LeaveHall :: 
"STUDENT set => STUDENT set => STUDENT set => STUDENT set => STUDENT =>
bool"
where
"LeaveHall badminton' badminton hall' hall leaver == 
(
(leaver \<in> hall) \<and> (hall' = hall \<setminus> {(leaver)})   
<and>
(badminton' = badminton)
)"
```

What it doesnt like i the expression "(hall' = hall \ {(leaver)})
    "

I'm trying to say is the set hall' is the set hall minus the term leaver.
But it just doesnt like it. Ive tried putting brackets and things and it
still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `∖` symbol exists in Isabelle under the name `\<setminus>`, it is not used at the moment. The proper syntax for set difference is quite simply `-`, so this works:

```
definition LeaveHall :: "STUDENT set ⇒ STUDENT set ⇒ STUDENT set ⇒ STUDENT set ⇒ STUDENT ⇒ bool"
  where "LeaveHall badminton' badminton hall' hall leaver ⟷
             leaver ∈ hall ∧ hall' = hall - {leaver} ∧ badminton' = badminton"
```

If you want to use `\<setminus>`, you can, of course, define an abbreviation with that syntax:

```
abbreviation setminus (infixl "∖" 65) where "setminus ≡ op -"
```

Or, to only allow this to input terms but not use it when printing terms:

```
abbreviation (input) setminus (infixl "∖" 65) where "setminus ≡ op -"
```

On an unrelated note: identifiers consisting of multiple words are typically written with underscores in Isabelle as opposed to Camel Case. Of course, you can call your identifiers whatever you want, but the convention is to use underscores instead of Camel Case.

Also, note that I used `⟷` in the definition of `LeaveHall` above, not the meta equality `≡` (as you did) or regular equality `=`. The use of  the meta equality operator `≡` in definitions is discouraged (although it has no real disadvantages).

The Boolean equivalence operator `⟷` is simply an abbreviation for equality on Booleans (so it's exactly the same as writing `=`). So why use `⟷`? Because it has lower precedence than `=`, which means you typically need fewer parentheses: `P a = Q a ∧ R a` is parsed as `(P a = Q a) ∧ R a`, whereas `P a ⟷ Q a ∧ R a` is parsed as `P a = (Q a ∧ R a)`.

Comment: `≡` has also advantages: it can often save a pair of parantheses.